# Как улучшить код?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт на битриксе. Мне необходимо выводить определенную надпись на некоторых страницах (их больше, чем в приведенном примере кода).Знаний в php сейчас нет, но удалось собрать вот такое и оно работает. Но есть подозрения, что это не очень хорошее решение. Как решить эту задачу лучше?

```
<?if ( preg_match('#/catalog/dent/#i', $APPLICATION->GetCurDir()) ): ?>
  <div>
  Необходима консультация специалиста
  </div>
<?endif?> 
<?if ( preg_match('#/catalog/hospitals/#i', $APPLICATION->GetCurDir()) ): ?>
  <div>
  Необходима консультация специалиста
  </div>
<?endif?>
```

Comment: `preg_match` можно заменить на `stristr`. `endif` заменить на `elseif`

Comment: и все? А как то сократить эту конструкцию возможно? Просто там порядка 10 выражений описывается. Получается громоздко. Может есть более оптимальное решение?

Comment: Только если разный текст выводить непосредственно на каждой 10 или скольких-то там страницы. А значит отрисовку этого блока с текстом надо переносить в каждую страницу отдельно, что тоже не совсем удобно.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что `$APPLICATION->GetCurDir()` возвращает такие-же пути? т.е. `/catalog/dent/`, `/catalog/hospitals/` и т.д.?

Comment: @Manitikyl это на вроде подтверждение, что да, сейчас та страница на которой надо выводить надпись, или не та

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('/catalog/dent/', '/catalog/hospitals/');
if ( in_array($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), $array) )
{
    echo '<div>Необходима консультация специалиста</div>';
}
```

Переделаете под себя.

Comment: не работает. Я прописала все необходимые пути. В том виде, что у вас, затем оформила так как у меня, но ни тот, ни другой вариант не сработал